# Is $53$ expressible in this form?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It seems as if prime numbers may always be expressed in the form $a\cdot 2^b+c \cdot 3^d$ for some nonnegative integers $b,d$ and $a,c\in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Examples:

$2=1\cdot 2^1+0\cdot 3^d$

$3=0\cdot 2^b+1\cdot 3^1$

$5=1\cdot 2^1+1\cdot 3^1$

$7=1\cdot 2^2+1\cdot 3^1$

$11=1\cdot 2^3+1\cdot 3^1$

$13=1\cdot 2^2+1\cdot 3^2$

$17=1\cdot 2^3+1\cdot 3^2$

$19=1\cdot 2^4+1\cdot 3^1$

$23=1\cdot 2^5+(-1)\cdot 3^2$

$29=1\cdot 2^5+(-1)\cdot 3^1$

$31=1\cdot 2^5+(-1)\cdot 3^0$

$37=1\cdot 2^6+(-1)\cdot 3^3$

$41=1\cdot 2^5+1\cdot 3^2$

$43=1\cdot 2^4+1\cdot 3^3$

$47=1\cdot 2^7+(-1)\cdot 3^4$

We hit a brick wall at $53$. Can anyone confirm if $53$ is/isn't expressible?

What about $n\in \mathbb{N}$ in general? Is it possible to always express $n$ in this form?

Thanks.

EDIT: I invented this question on my own, there are no sources.

Note: The reason I started with prime numbers is because I found it hard to find an expression for $6$, whereas prime numbers continued to be easy to find expressions for (easy until $53$, that is).

Comment: This is exactly the content of http://oeis.org/A103146 , which seems to claim that there is no way to write $53$ in the form $\pm 2^b \pm 3^d$. A few lines of code shows that there is no solution for $b, d \leq 50$.

Comment: As to your second question (with regards to $n\in\mathbb{N}$): Pillai's conjecture states that for any given positive integer $k$ there are only a finite number of pairs of perfect powers whose difference is $k$. This is an unsolved problem.

Comment: Notice that allowing the coefficient to be $0$ gains nothing here: If either coefficient is $0$, then the resulting integer is a power of $2$ or $3$, and the only such numbers that are prime are $2$ and $3$ themselves, and these can be written without $0$ coefficients as $-2^0 + 3^1$ and $2^1 + 3^0$.

Comment: It is straightforward to check that $53$ is not the sum between a power of two and a power of three. Since both $2$ and $3$ are generators for $G=\mathbb{F}_{53}^*$ and $53\mid 2^8+3^2$, it follows that:

$$2\equiv 3^{49}\pmod{53},\qquad 3\equiv 2^{17}\pmod{53}, $$
and
$$ 2^a \equiv 3^b \pmod{53} $$
implies $a\equiv 17b\pmod{52}$. This might help.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that for any $k,l$ we have that
$$2^k \not\equiv 3^l+53 \pmod{117}$$ 
and that
$$2^k+53 \not\equiv 3^l\pmod{117}$$ 
Just enumerating the different powers.

Edit: If you consider the sets $Q_t = \{2^{k_1}3^{k_2}\dots p_t^{k_t}, k_1,\dots,k_t \ge 0\}$ and ask for integers not in $Q_t$ or sum or difference of elements in $Q_t$ then I found using this method that 103 is the smallest using primes up to 3 and that 583 is the smallest using primes up to 5 and I conjecture that 3737, 16579 and 41969 are the least integers using primes up to 7, 11 and 13 resp.

It seems probable  that there is always an integer that can't be written in this way for any set of primes but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Ark I used PARI GP, the powers of 3 mod 117 are just 3,9,27,81 and the powers of 2 are 1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 16, 22, 32, 44, 59, 64, 88 so it is easy to check

Answer (score 1):

Let's count the positive integers up to $X$ of the shape $2^b+3^d$. It is easy to see that there are at most a constant times $\log^2 X$ of them. That the same statement is true for integers of the shape $|2^b-3^d|$ is much less obvious, but follows from what are called lower bounds for linear forms in logarithms (for this exact problem, they were first used by Ellison in the 1970s). In particular, the number of positive integers in $[1,X]$ that can be written as $a \cdot 2^b + c \cdot 3^d$ is at most a constant times $\log^2 X$. It follows that, for any dense enough set of integers, most of them will not be of the form $a \cdot 2^b + c \cdot 3^d$. In the case of the primes, there are of order $X/\log X$ of them up to $X$, essentially 100% of which are not of the desired form. A like conclusion is reached if you ask the same question about, for example, squares, cubes, or Carmichael numbers.